# Alterando valor de um campo em um select

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Query:

```
select id_cliente,nm_cliente,tp_sexo from tb_clientes;
```

[image: select id_cliente,nm_cliente,tp_sexo from tb_clientes;]

No meu banco o sexo está cadastrado como `int` gostaria que quando eu fizesse um `select` exibisse Masculino ou Feminino no lugar de `1` ou `2`, como eu faço isso?

Comment: Sexo é outra tabela?

Comment: Não é uma coluna da tabela clientes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**case ...when**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html):

```
select nm_cliente, case tp_sexo
when 1 then 'Masculino'
when 2 then 'feminino' end as strSexo
from  tb_clientes
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando no [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6291e/2)

**Referencias:**

http://imasters.com.br/artigo/18681/mysql/utilizando-select-case-com-mysql/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236770/case-within-a-select-case-in-mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Valeu cara, era exatamente isso!